Angular Material 18 color property ignored
I've created a new Angular app to test the M3 theme, no other styles are setup.
But this is how it looks from literally copy/pasting the code from Angular's example

My full CSS:
@use "@angular/material" as mat;
@use "m3-theme";
@include mat.core();
$test-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$azure-palette,
      tertiary: mat.$blue-palette,
    ),
    density: (
      scale: 0,
    ),
  )
);

:root {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($test-theme);
}

Did I miss a step?

please share github repo or stackblitz

is this css related to some component? if no, you probably want to use something instead of :root selector

@NarenMurali I tried it, but there are just too many errors I can't even get it working with Angular 18 and SCSS.

@Andrei This is for global, I want all components. Same issue happens if I put it on body. I'm basically using everything that the default code generated is giving me.

@Shadoweb I had the same problem please raise a issue on angular github

@Shadoweb Here is a stackblitz for reproducing the issue!

Try this:
@use "@angular/material" as mat;
@use "m3-theme";

@include mat.core();

$test-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$azure-palette,
      tertiary: mat.$blue-palette,
    ),
    density: (
      scale: 0,
    ),
  )
);

//
@include mat.color-variants-backwards-compatibility($test-theme);
//

:root {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($test-theme);
}

